# centering a few links inside a container that is 1000% width?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of nav items that I want to eventually be able to swipe through so I've created an unordered list which initially has a width of 1000% for testing and the links are positioned inline-block. This works well if there are enough links to fill the whole width of the page but if there is only a few links they get stuck to the left of the nav, ideally what I would like to do is have these centered. Ive tried adding `text-align: center` to the nav but this centers the links in the 1000% wide space and not the 100% page width. Can anyone recommend a solution as I thought this may be achievable with just CSS

**JS Fiddle** (with just a few links): http://jsfiddle.net/HS4VE/

**CSS**

```
nav {
    padding: 10px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    zoom: 1;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
}

nav a {
    color: white;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #454545), color-stop(100%, #363636));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#454545, #363636);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#454545, #363636);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#454545, #363636);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#454545, #363636);
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    width: 186px;
    display: block;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
  }

nav a.is-active {
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#fe57ae), to(#fe329b));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fe57ae, #fe329b);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#fe57ae, #fe329b);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#fe57ae, #fe329b);
background-image: linear-gradient(#fe57ae, #fe329b);
}

.inner {
    width: 1000%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
.inner {
    white-space:nowrap;
    max-width: 1000%;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HS4VE/3/

Comment: hi, when i resize now the links fall below each other. I want them to remain side by side no matter what the browser width is?

Comment: Good one! 
I did it differently, and not as sophisticated. 
I centered the inner so it would be "slidable" in both directions from center and out. 

.inner {
    width: 1000%;
    margin-left:-500%;
    padding-left:50%;
}

http://jsfiddle.net/HS4VE/4/